# JQuery smooth animation for an auto-width div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Directy this is a fragment of my current projecet.

Please click [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj9VH/1/) here.

Simply, I created a list containing these buttons:

```
 <a href="#f1" class="bt">1
    <div class="show">Computers Networking</div>
  </a>
```

and when mouseover `bt` button, the tips `show` slide to the right.

The question is, as you have seen in the demo, it cannot grow smoothly and the words appears suddenly. If I fixed the width of tips, this porblem solved, but not what I want.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the width of content inside of div `.show` using javascript `scrollWidth`

```
var showWidth = $(this).find('.show')[0].scrollWidth;
```

Then call that variable in your function

```
$(".jumper .bt").mouseover(function(){
    console.log("faqffff");
    var showWidth = $(this).find('.show')[0].scrollWidth;
    $(this).find(".show").css({'width':showWidth+'px', 'padding':'0 10px'});
});
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj9VH/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [**`animate()`**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function you can archive this smooth animation

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj9VH/2/)</kbd>

```
$(".jumper .bt").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find(".show").animate({width:'200px', padding: "0 10px"}, '700');
});
$(".jumper .bt").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find(".show").animate({'width':'0', padding: "0"}, '700');
});
```

---

### jQuery Animate() Method

#### Syntax

> .animate( {css_properties} [, duration ] [, easing ] [, callback_function ] )

#### Duration

- milliseconds (1000 miliseconds = 1sec)
- "slow"
- "fast"

#### easing

- "swing" - starting and ending move slower and middle move faster
- "linear" - move same speed

#### Callback_function

When done specified function call.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a jsfiddle for you for smooth animation,here is code check out.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hj9VH/5/

```
 $.easing.elasout = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
};

$(".jumper .bt").mouseover(function(){
    console.log("faqffff");
    $(this).find(".show").css({'width':'auto', 'padding':'0 10px'},'1000','swing');
  });
  $(".jumper .bt").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find(".show").animate({'width':'0', 'padding':'0'},'500','elasout');
  });
```